# Create instance of unmanaged dll class

Tags: c#, .net, dll, unmanaged

How do I create a class that I can reference to and directly use to call methods from an unmanaged dll? (assuming an unmanaged dll is a dll that doesn't exists/is known @ compile time)

For example I have a dll which contains the class helloWorld and I want to create an instance of the class and then call helloWorld.tell().

Comment: Dynamic does not always mean unmanaged.

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo could you explain the differents?

Comment: C# is a managed language, it uses a garbage collector for it's memory management.  C++ is not managed-you must manage memory yourself. You can dynamically load a C# assembly and use reflection to load up classes, call methods, and all of that.  This would be a dynamic, managed, assembly.

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo I see. Than its managed. I thought meant you didn't know the content of the dll @ runtime. the question stil stand on how to get an instance of it. Thanks for explaining so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your assembly with a COM interface, which is available from unmanaged code.

There are some examples here that you can download. Check out the COM Interop Part II code. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Visual-Studio-2010-Samples-31b491f3

If you're feeling brave, here's another explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645738(v=vs.71).aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: The OP was confused about unmanaged versus dynamic assemblies. I don't think this is what they were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to dynamically load an assembly, not neccessarily work with an unmanaged assembly.  It seems you are looking for information on [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  You can use [`Activator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to create the objects you need.  There are a lot of ways to do this, and I would read up on it.  Here are a few resources to get started:

[Code Project - Reflection in C# Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/C__Reflection_Tutorial.aspx)

[CSharp.Net - Reflection Introduction](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/reflection/introduction/)

[CodeGuru.com - An Introduction to Reflection](http://www.codeguru.com/Csharp/Csharp/cs_misc/reflection/article.php/c4257)